# Can I run appcmd.exe using shell

Tags: python-3.x

I tried several ways to run appcmd to add a (non Python) site to IIS
My latest try is to run it as administrator

```
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
cmdCommand ="c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add site /name:test2.query.api /bindings:http/*:80:test2.api /physicalPath:c:\inetpub\wwwroot_test2"
shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile='cmd.exe', lpParameters='/c '+cmdCommand)
```

I get 'Process finished with exit code 0'
But my new site is not in IIS

If I run the same command from the DOS prompt it works

I want to write an Installer, that first copies the files to inetpub and finally to add the sites to ISS.

First part works, but now I don't get the sites in IIS

(Python 3.6.2rc1)

Comment: have you tried adding raw string prefix: `cmdCommand = r"c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe...`